# Is abruptly phase change a dominant cause in observable interferece pattern?

Tags: interference

In newton's ring, plane parallel film or in measuring thickness of a paper we see interference pattern confirming wave nature of light. Will interference be observable if we let there is no phase change in hard reflection? Is abruptly phase change a necessary condition for observing interference pattern?

Comment: Are you referring to the phase change of $\pi$ when light reflects from the air/glass boundary?

Comment: No it's not necessary. If the $\pi$ phase change wasn't there, the only effect would be that the dark and light lines would have switched.

Comment: yes. @JohnRennie

Comment: what do you mean by switched? @Ali